# SQL Server 2008 R2 First Time Login

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, authentication, ssms

I've just started work on a new computer in which I had to download all the software fresh.

I've just download a copy of SQL Server 2008 R2, and I'm trying to connect to SQL Server Management Studio without success. I vaguely remember last time I installed this, it asked me to choose between windows, or sql server authentication, however this didn't happen for this installation.

If I try to login via Windows Authentication (where the username and password fields are greyed out, localhost as server name) it gives the following error:

> "A Network-related or instance
>   specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 2)"

I have checked everything in SQL Server Configuration Manager, and everything bar VIA is enabled.

If I try SQL Server Authentication, It asks me for a username and password which I definiately have not set yet. Also, under SQL Server Services in configuration manager, there is nothing there.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

PS: I don't know if it's worth mentioning but I am running Windows 7 as a virtual machine on a Mac.

Comment: Hmmm. Would this be under SQL Server Services in Confg Manager? If so, strangely enough, there is nothing there??

Comment: The sql server service can be administered from SQL Config Manager via the SQL Server Services node or the Services Management Snap in (type services.msc in the Search bar or Run box.

If the services isn't found in services.msc you should first reboot in case the service install was delayed for some reason, and then try a repair on the SQL Server install

Comment: @crippledsmurf, I'll reboot and let you know :)

Comment: There should be stuff there. I have three nodes Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS) SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Browser. The fact that you see nothing means SQL Config Manager can't find the services, it's most likely because they aren't registered properly or at all. If sql config manager is not running as admin, thaat might be a reason although the app requests admin rights by default so rights issues aren't likely.

Comment: @crippledsmurf, I tried a repair install even, and there are still no services at all present under SQL Server Services in config manager. I'm really at a loss :S

Comment: Confirm that the binary is present here `%PROGRAMFILES%\\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"

If not then possibly check what permissions the installer is running with also look in the System and Application event logs for any sign of issues, also the installler creates its own event log, I can't recall the default location for that though

Comment: @crippledsmurf, I ended up just doing a fresh install, from a fresh download. I seemed to be asked the right options re. instances, usernames, passwords and it's working fine now. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up reinstalling completely and doing a fresh install from a fresh download. When I did this I was brought through the steps of selecting the default instance, and selecting authentication modes.

Working fine now :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have the correct instance name? If it was SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition then the default instance name is .\SQLEXPRESS.

Also if your using sql authentication to connect try running sql management studio as admin, if you are a limited user your identity might not be mapped to an account in sql server yet but i believe the Administrators user group is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if your services are running.

Please type

> net start mssqlserver

in your command prompt. Then try to login.

Comment: Hi Sachin, I have tried that. There don't appear to be any services present to begin with :-S

Comment: @109221793 - Are you sure you have administrator rights on that machine? Also you can try to put dot(.) in place of localhost and try to login once.

Comment: Worked for me. But for that you have to run your **Command Prompt** as **Run As Administrator** :)

Answer (score 0):

After checking tons of sites looking for an answer to this question, I think I have a simple solution.

1. Open the sql Server Configuration
2. Click on the sql server services node
3. Right Click on Sql server
4. Click Start.

I have been screwing around with this forever, and this simple method actually worked.